# Issue injecting helm value on configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, helm3

can someone help?
I am trying to inject a helm value on a config map, but it breaks the format. If I use the value directly instead of .Values, it works fine.

What I have:

```
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: |
    name: Okta
    issuer: https://mycompany.okta.com
    clientID: {{ .Values.okta.clientID }}
    clientSecret: {{ .Values.okta.clientSecret }}
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}}
```

The result

```
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: "name: Okta\nissuer: https://mycompany.okta.com\nclientID: myClientId \nclientSecret:
    mySecret\nrequestedScopes: [\"openid\", \"profile\",
    \"email\", \"groups\"]\nrequestedIDTokenClaims: {\"groups\": {\"essential\": true}}\n"
```

Comment: Without digging in too deeply, that seems okay; the result has an inline double-quoted string with `\n` newlines, as opposed to a block scalar on multiple lines, but they should be the same YAML content.  Which specific thing isn't getting passed through correctly?

Comment: @David Maze it does not work. It says the yaml is malformed

Comment: What values are you using?  (Try, say, `helm template --debug --set okta.clientId=id --set okra.clientSecret=passw0rd .` for an example output that doesn't use your real credentials.)  Is it actually split out on to three lines like you show in the sample?

Comment: @DavidMaze it does not matter the value. The issue is that the moment I use helm values inside that `oidc.config` value, it breaks the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of tries, it worked when I skipped the a whitespace at the beginning

```
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: |
    name: Okta
    issuer: "https://mycompany.okta.com"
    clientID: {{- .Values.okta.clientId }}
    clientSecret: {{- .Values.okta.clientSecret }}
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}}
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be with the values.yaml . it worked for me in both ways :

1. using the values in values.yaml

---

Values.yaml:

```
okta:
  clientSecret: test1233
  clientID: testnew
```

configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: test
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: |
    name: Okta
    issuer: https://mycompany.okta.com
    clientID: {{ .Values.okta.clientID }}
    clientSecret: {{ .Values.okta.clientSecret }}
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}}
```

---

command used :

```
 helm install testchart .\mycharttest --dry-run
```

-----Output-------------------

```
# Source: mycharttest/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: test
    product: test
    db: test
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: |
    name: Okta
    issuer: https://mycompany.okta.com
    clientID: testnew
    clientSecret: test1233
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}}
```

2. using the values in runtime

---

---Command --

```
 helm install test .\mycharttest --dry-run --set okta.clientID=newclientid --set okta.clientSecret=newsecret
```

----Output ---

```
# Source: mycharttest/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: test
    product: test
    db: test
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  oidc.config: |
    name: Okta
    issuer: https://mycompany.okta.com
    clientID: newclientid
    clientSecret: newsecret
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}
```

kubernetes version : 1.22
Helm version :
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.7.1", GitCommit:"1d11fcb5d3f3bf00dbe6fe31b8412839a96b3dc4", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.16.9"}

Answer (score 1):

The easy way store everything into the **file** and use it directly first

file `oidc.config`

```
name: Okta
issuer: https://mycompany.okta.com
clientID: clientID 
clientSecret: clientSecret
requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
requestedIDTokenClaims: {"groups": {"essential": true}}
```

**helm**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "oidc.config" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
        {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```

Reference doc : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/

Also checkout this similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209432/5525824